# Is there a Character.toChar?

Tags: java, character

I know that I can use Character.toChars to get a char[] from the codepoint.
So far I have:

```
public static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] buffer = new char[bytes.length];
    int i = 0;
    for (byte aByte : bytes) {
        buffer[i] = Character.toChars(aByte)[0];
        i++;
    }
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

And it works.  But I would rather skip the char[] and go straight to the char.  Every time I search I get what I have above.  I was hoping for something a little cleaner.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? You know, `byte` and `char` are two different primitive types for a reason...

Answer (score 1):

The code you have is probably the best you're going to find if you intend to use the Character class. And in all honesty -- it doesn't even look that messy. I'd say stick with it.

The entire method is unnecessary, however. The String class has a constructor where you can turn an array of bytes into a String.

```
String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
```

Use it like this:

```
String str = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Actually, the existing code is broken because of sign extension when you widen a `byte` to an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Erm ... here's the problem.  Your current code is *probably* broken.  It will work for text encoded in ASCII, but for most encodings you are liable to get garbling, or exceptions.

What your currently currently does is to assume that you have 8-bit encoding, and assume that there each 8-bit value can be cast to an `int` and that `int` will be the correct Unicode code-point.  So consider what happens with `0xA1` - the LATIN-1 "inverted exclamation mark" character.  The Java byte value for that is decimal 161 - 256 == -105, which is -105 when the `byte` is widened to an `int`.  But as an `int` that gives you `0xFFFFFFA1`.  That isn't a legal Unicode codepoint, so the call to `toChars` should throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.

OK, so what would be the right way to convert the `byte[]` to a `char[]` ... assuming that the bytes are encoded in LATIN-1?

Simply this:

```
String s = new String(bytes, "LATIN-1");
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
```

And since you really want the characters as a String ... you can do this:

```
return new String(bytes, "LATIN-1");
```

The same will work for a variety of other character encodings, provided that you know the encoding's name and your Java installation implements it.  You can also provide the encoding as a `Charset` object.

Comment: Thank you for your quick and complete response.  I will have to get back to it in a minute and see what I need to do.  I do want my code to be robust, so I will certainly take your comments to heart.

Answer (score 0):

Since a char has 16 bits and a byte has 8 bits, you can simply...

`buffer[i] = aByte;`

Character.toChars expects an integer anyway, as a byte is not enough to identify every Unicode character. I hope you realize that your method will only work for 8-bit texts anyway? As soon as you try to read a unicode text this way, you will encounter problems, as a unicode character can need more than one byte to be identified properly...

Why do you need that method anyway? Why not simply...

`new String( bytes );`

...or even preferably...

`new String(bytes, someCharSet);`